# Format distance (meters/kilometers/foot/miles) with just meters as input, according to the users locale

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to convert this Swift code, which converts given meters to a formatter string, taking into account the users locale and auto formats large meters to kilometers (e.g. 1234 meters -> 1.234 km). I am trying to find out if Kotlin in Android supports this somehow:

```
private let measureFormatter: MeasurementFormatter = {
    let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()

    formatter.unitOptions = .naturalScale
    formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

    return formatter
}()

func formatMeters(meters: Double) -> String {
    measureFormatter.string(for: Measurement(value: meters, unit: UnitLength.meters)!
}
```

I now check manually for the measurement system and check if the number is large enough to fit better in a larger measurement. I don't like this manually way of checking and I hope there is a better native equivalent of this code:

```
private val measureMeterFormatter = NumberFormatter
    .withLocale(usersLocale)
    .precision(Precision.maxFraction(0))
    .unit(MeasureUnit.METER)

private val measureKilometerFormatter = NumberFormatter
    .withLocale(usersLocale)
    .precision(Precision.maxFraction(0))
    .unit(MeasureUnit.KILOMETER)

private val measureFootFormatter = NumberFormatter
    .withLocale(usersLocale)
    .precision(Precision.maxFraction(0))
    .unit(MeasureUnit.FOOT)

private val measureMileFormatter = NumberFormatter
    .withLocale(usersLocale)
    .precision(Precision.maxFraction(0))
    .unit(MeasureUnit.MILE)

fun formatMeters(meters: Double): String {
    val measurement = LocaleData.getMeasurementSystem(usersULocale)

    return formatMeters(meters = meters, useUS = measurement == LocaleData.MeasurementSystem.US)
}

fun formatMeters(meters: Double, useUS: Boolean): String {
    return if (useUS) {
        val miles = meters * 0.00062137119

        if (miles >= 1) {
            measureMileFormatter.format(miles)
        } else {
            val feet = meters * 3.281

            measureFootFormatter.format(feet)
        }
    } else {
        if (meters <= 1_000) {
            measureMeterFormatter.format(meters)
        } else {
            val kilometers = meters / 1_000

            measureKilometerFormatter.format(kilometers)
        }
    }.toString()
}
```

Comment: Nothing built in, but there's libraries that do what you want.  The big difficulty would be to find the automatic mile->feet and km->m part, that's a bit unusual. I'd also, if you're doing any kind of math, consider going with a Length class which would not only make your code clearer but allow you to store units with the scalar value and prevent unit confusion in your code.  Kotlin has operator overloading so the math could still look the same.